# Not able to combine GROUP BY, ORDER BY, and UNION

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, sql-order-by, union

```
SELECT TOP 1 o.OrderID,e.FirstName+''+e.Lastname,COUNT(DISTINCT p.ProductID) AS [NUMBER OF PRODUCTS], DATEDIFF(DAY,o.OrderDate,o.RequiredDate) AS [DAYS TAKEN FOR DELIVERY], s.CompanyName 
  FROM Orders o, Shippers s, Products p, Employee e, OrderDetails oe 
 WHERE o.ShipperID=s.ShipperID AND e.EmployeeID=o.EmployeeID 
   AND o.OrderID=oe.OrderID AND oe.ProductID=p.ProductID
 GROUP BY o.OrderID,s.CompanyName,o.OrderDate,o.RequiredDate,e.FirstName,e.LastName
 ORDER BY ABS(DATEDIFF(DAY,o.OrderDate,o.RequiredDate)) ASC
UNION
SELECT TOP 1 o.OrderID,e.FirstName+''+e.Lastname,COUNT(DISTINCT p.ProductID) AS [NUMBER OF PRODUCTS], DATEDIFF(DAY,o.OrderDate,o.RequiredDate) AS [DAYS TAKEN FOR DELIVERY], s.CompanyName 
  FROM Orders o, Shippers s, Products p, Employee e, OrderDetails oe 
 WHERE o.ShipperID=s.ShipperID AND e.EmployeeID=o.EmployeeID 
   AND o.OrderID=oe.OrderID AND oe.ProductID=p.ProductID
GROUP BY o.OrderID,s.CompanyName,o.OrderDate,o.RequiredDate,e.FirstName,e.LastName
ORDER BY ABS(DATEDIFF(DAY,o.OrderDate,o.RequiredDate)) DESC;
```

Comment: Don't destroy the question.  Don't SHOUT the whole time in the title, either.  And do format your SQL for some semblance of readability.

Comment: plz, provide a DB structure and details of runtime exception in Your question

Comment: Do not vandalize your posts. By posting on this site, you've irrevocably granted the Stack Exchange network the right to distribute that content under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/) for as long as it sees fit to do so. For alternatives to deletion, see: [I've thought better of my question; can I delete it?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question)

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: ANSI joins are standard. Try use join by using keyword (INNER JOIN / LEFT JOIN or etc). Never use joins like that.

Answer (score 1):

Use the parenthesis as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT TOP 1 o.OrderID,e.FirstName+''+e.Lastname,COUNT(DISTINCT p.ProductID) AS [NUMBER OF PRODUCTS], DATEDIFF(DAY,o.OrderDate,o.RequiredDate) AS [DAYS TAKEN FOR DELIVERY], s.CompanyName 
  FROM Orders o, Shippers s, Products p, Employee e, OrderDetails oe 
 WHERE o.ShipperID=s.ShipperID AND e.EmployeeID=o.EmployeeID 
   AND o.OrderID=oe.OrderID AND oe.ProductID=p.ProductID
 GROUP BY o.OrderID,s.CompanyName,o.OrderDate,o.RequiredDate,e.FirstName,e.LastName
 ORDER BY ABS(DATEDIFF(DAY,o.OrderDate,o.RequiredDate)) ASC)
UNION
(SELECT TOP 1 o.OrderID,e.FirstName+''+e.Lastname,COUNT(DISTINCT p.ProductID) AS [NUMBER OF PRODUCTS], DATEDIFF(DAY,o.OrderDate,o.RequiredDate) AS [DAYS TAKEN FOR DELIVERY], s.CompanyName 
  FROM Orders o, Shippers s, Products p, Employee e, OrderDetails oe 
 WHERE o.ShipperID=s.ShipperID AND e.EmployeeID=o.EmployeeID 
   AND o.OrderID=oe.OrderID AND oe.ProductID=p.ProductID
GROUP BY o.OrderID,s.CompanyName,o.OrderDate,o.RequiredDate,e.FirstName,e.LastName
ORDER BY ABS(DATEDIFF(DAY,o.OrderDate,o.RequiredDate)) DESC);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't have an `ORDER BY` in the first part of the `UNION` unless you put the main portion of the query in a subquery like so.

```
SELECT * 
FROM
(
    SELECT TOP 1 
        o.OrderID,
        e.FirstName + '' + e.Lastname,
        COUNT(DISTINCT p.ProductID) AS [NUMBER OF PRODUCTS],
        DATEDIFF(DAY, o.OrderDate, o.RequiredDate) AS [DAYS TAKEN FOR DELIVERY], 
        s.CompanyName  
    FROM 
        Orders o, 
        JOIN Shippers s ON o.ShipperID = s.ShipperID, 
        JOIN Employee e ON e.EmployeeID = o.EmployeeID,
        JOIN OrderDetails oe ON oe.ProductID = o.OrderID,
        JOIN Products p ON p.ProductID = oe.ProductID  
    GROUP BY 
        o.OrderID,
        s.CompanyName,
        o.OrderDate,
        o.RequiredDate,
        e.FirstName,
        e.LastName
    ORDER BY 
        ABS(DATEDIFF(DAY, o.OrderDate, o.RequiredDate))
)

UNION

SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT TOP 1 
        o.OrderID,
        e.FirstName + '' + e.Lastname,
        COUNT(DISTINCT p.ProductID) AS [NUMBER OF PRODUCTS], 
        DATEDIFF(DAY, o.OrderDate, o.RequiredDate) AS [DAYS TAKEN FOR DELIVERY], 
        s.CompanyName 
    FROM 
        Orders o, 
        JOIN Shippers s ON o.ShipperID = s.ShipperID, 
        JOIN Employee e ON e.EmployeeID = o.EmployeeID,
        JOIN OrderDetails oe ON oe.ProductID = o.OrderID,
        JOIN Products p ON p.ProductID = oe.ProductID 
    GROUP BY 
        o.OrderID,
        s.CompanyName,
        o.OrderDate,
        o.RequiredDate,
        e.FirstName,
        e.LastName
    ORDER BY 
        ABS(DATEDIFF(DAY, o.OrderDate, o.RequiredDate)) DESC
)
```

Side note, if you format your SQL similar to the above it's much easier to read and find problems that may exist.

Comment: I WANT 1ST QUERY TO BE ORDERED BY ASC AND 2ND QUERY TO BE ORDERED BY DESC. THE QUESTION IS IS AS FOLLOWS : Which orders took the least number and maximum number of shipping days?

Comment: See my latest edit. There's an alternate method using `ROW_NUMBER()` that may give you better performance as well, but this will work and is most similar to your original query.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't repeat the query.  Use a CTE:

```
WITH cte as (
      SELECT o.OrderID, e.FirstName + '' + e.Lastname, COUNT(DISTINCT p.ProductID) AS [NUMBER OF PRODUCTS],
             DATEDIFF(DAY,o.OrderDate,o.RequiredDate) AS [DAYS TAKEN FOR DELIVERY], s.CompanyName 
      FROM Orders o JOIN
           Shippers s
           ON o.ShipperID = s.ShipperID JOIN
           Employee e
           ON e.EmployeeID = o.EmployeeID JOIN
           OrderDetails oe 
           ON o.OrderID = oe.OrderID JOIN
           Products p
           ON oe.ProductID = p.ProductID
      GROUP BY o.OrderID, s.CompanyName, o.OrderDate, o.RequiredDate, e.FirstName, e.LastName
     )
SELECT *
FROM ((SELECT TOP (1) cte.*
       FROM cte
       ORDER BY ABS(DATEDIFF(DAY, o.OrderDate, o.RequiredDate))
      ) UNION ALL
      (SELECT TOP (1) cte.*
       FROM cte
       ORDER BY ABS(DATEDIFF(DAY, o.OrderDate, o.RequiredDate)) DESC
      ) 
     ) x;
```

Note the use of proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax.  **Do not use archaic syntax such a commas in the `FROM` clause.**

Unfortunately, SQL Server actually evaluates the CTE twice, just as it would with two subqueries.  An alternative method gets around this:

```
select cte.*
from (select cte.*,
             row_number() over (order by ABS(DATEDIFF(DAY, o.OrderDate, o.RequiredDate))) as seqnum_asc,
             row_number() over (order by ABS(DATEDIFF(DAY, o.OrderDate, o.RequiredDate)) desc) as seqnum_desc
      from cte
     ) cte
where 1 in (seqnum_asc, seqnum_desc);
```